# How to use virtual function with enum?

Tags: c++, enums, virtual-functions

Update the question,

I'm trying to using enum passing the parameter to virtual function.
I want to  practice the Strategy mode of design pattern.
Here is my code(example) ,which should print "Hello".(C++),
I ran but error,
Error message:

```
 undefined reference to `test(Enum)'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
compiler exit status 1
```

please help tell me where wrong.

```
    class Base
{
  public:
  virtual void show() = 0;
};

class child1 : public Base
{
  public:
  void show(){
      cout<<"Hello"<<endl;
  };
};

enum Enum {
    child1,child2,
};



int main() {
    Base* test(Enum);
auto the_test =test(child1);
the_test->show();
    return 0;
}
```

I have no idea where wrong.please help to tell me.

thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Also please take some time to read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). For example about information we need to know: What is `CreateA`? What does it do? And what do you mean by "it's not working"?

Comment: It gets passed the same way as any other type is passed.

Comment: *I'm trying to using enum passing the parameter to virtual function*  This code does not do that.  It declares a function called `CreateA`, which looks like a factory function, but is not provided.  Then takes the `tea_a` pointer returned, and calls the `Make()` method, which does not take any parameters.

Comment: Sorry , my question is not clear, i try to update.

Comment: The message "undefined reference to `test(Enum)'" means you haven't defined (implemented) the function `test`. You *declare* the function but you never define it.

Comment: I'm don't know how to fix the code ,  i try this "Base *test=new child1();
 test->show();" and comment out the enum Enum {
    child1,child2,
}; ,which print "Hello", but i need to pass parameter by enum.